# Qual a Diferença entre Select e Execute em uma Procedure?

Tags: sql, firebird, stored-procedures, firebird-2.5

Existe alguma diferença entre fazer um Select para chamar a Procedure e dar um Execute na Procedure, por exemplo, no select a procedure está em modo Read-Only e no execute não?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `select` tem o intuito de retornar dados, portanto ele deve executar algo que possua um retorno, no caso de `procedures` é obrigatório que haja um `suspend` para ser executada com `select`.

Já o `execute stored procedure` tem o intuito de executar ações de alterações de dados/armazenamento de dados que não exija um retorno.
Porem pode conter retorno se utilizado junto a ele o `RETURNING_VALUES`.

Exemplo:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE MakeFullName
  :FirstName, :MiddleName, :LastName
  RETURNING_VALUES :FullName;
```

Quanto a questão de `Read-Only` ou não, isso é independente do comando escolhido para execução, é definido na transação da conexão.